# Why is there sometimes a rescue pod icon in the HUD?

Tags: subnautica

I noticed that sometimes a small rescue pod icon is displayed in the HUD. It does not show the position of the pod, it stays always in the same position:

[image]

[image]

<sub>(red circle by me for highlighting, not actually there in game)</sub>

It doesn't matter if I'm in a vehicle, in a base, or just swimming around. I have the beacon of the pod disabled in my PDA. When I open the PDA and enable the beacon for my own pod the icon vanishes, but reappears after some time.

I first thought it is a hint to go to the pod for some reason, but I went there and couldn't see anything that required interaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a couple of threads on the Steam Forums, it's a display bug. You can fix it by turning the icon on and off again, although as you state yourself it's not a permanent fix.

Sources:

https://steamcommunity.com/app/264710/discussions/0/1700541698682034008/

https://steamcommunity.com/app/264710/discussions/0/1489987634011862756/

Comment: Hum, I didn't have the impression that it appears at a random position. I had the feeling that it is always in the same place, hence I assumed it's rather a feature than a bug. The next time it appears I'll report it as a bug. Maybe it will get fixed someday.